# Moving an object in front of the Player in Unity, based off player movement not player camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a pyramid that is supposed to move in front of the player after a set period of time and distance. If the player is looking the direction that are moving, everything works fine. If the player moves one direction and looks another, than they never encounter the pyramid. What do I need to do to get the pyramid to move in front of their movement and not their camera? Here's my current code for the movement:

```
Pyramid.transform.position = Player.transform.position + Player.transform.forward * PyramidToPlayerMoveDistance; 
        Pyramid.transform.LookAt(Player.transform, Vector3.up);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position your "pyramid" towards the movement of the player you could find the direction of movement. To do so you firstly need to find the velocity.The velocity is the difference between the new position and the last position.

```
velocity = newPlayerPos - oldPlayerPos
```

The vector direction is the normalized velocity.

```
direction = velocity.normalized
```

Then position the pyramid

```
Pyramid.transform.position = Player.transform.position + direction * PyramidToPlayerMoveDistance;
```

This is not tested, but supposed to work. Also I would recommend to use Linear interpolation to smooth the movement.

```
Vector3.Lerp(oldPyramidPost, newPyramidPos, Time.deltaTime * speed)
```

Comment: Using `Lerp` with `speed` or `Time.deltaTime` makes no sense! You either confuse it with `Vector3.MoveTowards` or would need to pass in a factor between `0` and `1` otherwise the object will only jitter but not move